# Split text separated by multiple blank spaces into multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, split, cell

I need to split the text contents of some cells into multiple columns.

The text inside the cells doesn't follow a precise pattern (e.g. a comma, semicolon...) but the pieces of text are separated by multiple blank spaces. Here is an example:

> Hi my name is Andrea (multiple blank spaces) I am good (multiple blank spaces) What about you?

I would like to split my text into three columns (one containing `Hi my name is Andrea`, the second containing `I am good` …).

The blank spaces between the sentences are not always the same (e.g. between `Andrea` and `I am good` there are 5 blank spaces while between `good` and `what about you` there are 7 blank spaces).

I thought that splitting the text when meeting more than one blank space could be a good idea. This is the code I tried:

```
Sub NameSplit()

    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant
    Dim x As String, cell As Range

    txt = ActiveCell.Value

    FullName = Split(txt, " ")

    For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)

        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: What about using 2 spaces as the delimiter?

Comment: @SJR but only in combination with `Trim$()` otherwise you will have left over spaces if there are a odd number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It would work with double space as delimiter. In combination with using `Trim$()` to remove left over spaces (eg. odd number of spaces is given the double space as delimiter results in a left over space in the begining of the following data).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NameSplit()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set Cell = Range("A1")

    Dim SplitData() As String
    SplitData = Split(Expression:=Cell.Value, Delimiter:="  ") 'double space as delimiter

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(SplitData) To UBound(SplitData)
        If Trim$(SplitData(i)) <> vbNullString Then
            Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=j).Value = Trim$(SplitData(i))
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It will turn

[image]

into

[image]

If you need to do it for multiple cells wrap the code into a loop.

```
For iRow = 1 To LastRow
    Set Cell = Cells(iRow, "A")
    ' …
Next iRow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to split your string into multiple columns

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim txt As String
Dim FullName() As String
Dim i As Long, colOffset As Long

Set rng = ActiveCell
txt = rng.Value2

FullName = Split(txt, String(2, " "))

For i = LBound(FullName) To UBound(FullName)
    If Not WorksheetFunction.Trim(FullName(i)) = vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Trim(FullName(i))
        colOffset = colOffset + 1
        rng.Offset(0, colOffset).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Trim(FullName(i))
    End If
Next i
```

outputting:

- Hi my name is Andrea
- I am good
- What about you?